# Split audio and video into two separate files

Tags: audio, video, quicktime, encoding

Is there a way (I'm thinking using QuickTime perhaps) of taking a video+audio file and splitting it into two separate files, one of just the video, and one of just the audio? I know that in Finder, there's a context menu item "Encode Selected Video Files" which lets you encode it as audio-only, but not as video-only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ffmpeg supports demuxing without re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv # show stream numbers and formats
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy audio.m4a # AAC
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy audio.mp3 # MP3
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy audio.ac3 # AC3
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -an -c copy video.mkv
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:a:1 -c copy audio.m4a # stream 1
```

`-c copy` is like `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`. `-map 0:1` means file 0, stream 1. `-an` means audio none.

-- Edited: -map 0:1 => -map 0:a:1 (pick 2nd audio not just 2nd any stream)

Comment: I easily used http://ffmpegmac.net/ to do this, and it was very fast and easy. +1 for no re-encoding.

Comment: Used this technique to extract one specific video stream from a multi-angle Xvid file for upload. +1

Answer (score 1):

[QuickTime 7 Pro](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL923) is the tool I have used for this splitting of tracks. Once you have registered the software, there is a nice tool that shows all tracks and you can delete them, move them, edit them separately.

Comment: Thanks, I might buy that if I can't figure out something in VLC.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the VLC player, my favorite, it will play anything and do anything.

Here is how the [splinting could work](http://darktips.com/split-video-audio-file/).

Here is where you can [download the VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html).

Comment: The first link is for splitting a file into smaller segments e.g. saving a 5-minute segment from a 1-hour video, and not for separating the video and audio streams. I'll look around VLC and see if I can find something, though.

Comment: It was just an example, maybe you want to read this one! http://www.ehow.com/how_8690780_split-videos-vlc.html